# On what factors does the electron density in a plasma depend?

Tags: plasma-physics

Pretty much what the title says. Any link to papers which give an explicit dependance of electron density in a plasma is welcome.

Comment: I hope temperature has crossed your mind

Comment: Of course it has. Temperature, magnetic field etc are all there,but i couldnt find any explicit mathematical dependance anywhere

Comment: Are you asking about partially or fully ionized plasmas?  If the former, then I assume you have ran across the Saha equation?

Comment: Yes i did see the saha equation, but i want equations corresponding to surface plasma of neutron stars. Is the saha equation the right one to use here? @honeste_vivere

Comment: @Lelouch I would suggest you add that specification to your question as its current form is so general/broad that it's nearly impossible to answer.  As to your question, an "ideal" neutron star magnetosphere has no plasma other than that produced by pair production since it is assumed the supernova explosion that preceded the neutron star excavated the system of pre-existing protons and electrons.

Comment: A simple answer could be _On the ionization rate_. Another one could be _On the number of neutrals available_. Also possible would be _On the temperature of the gas_. All of the answer would be correct. It is just hard to tell what you are asking for. Maybe you could add some context?